# How to redirect to 404 page with error status code in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I use server components (`app` router). If the server response is successful (record found in the database), then the page loads. If the record is not found or other server error, then the special `errorboundary` page is loaded. I used it at the development stage and this is a convenient tool. The problem is that after deploying the site, some pages can be indexed by search engines. If after time the page is deleted, then `Google` must get an error to remove the page from it's index. Is it possible to configure so that in case of an error, the correct code (404) will return and page `404` will be loaded? Thanks for any help.
Here is my component:

```
import Nodata from "@/components/Nodata";
import { IPost } from "@/misc/types";
import Post from "@/wrappers/Post";
import { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from "next";
import React from "react";

const HOST = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST;

type Props = {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
};

export async function generateMetadata(
  { params, searchParams }: Props,
  parent: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
  // read route params
  const slug = params.slug;

  // fetch data
  const data: IPost[] = await fetch(`${HOST}/api/news/${String(slug)}`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    });

  const content = data[0];

  return {
    metadataBase: new URL(String(HOST)),
    title: content.title,
    description: content.description,
    openGraph: {
      url: `${HOST}/news/${slug}`,
      title: content.title,
      description: content.description,
    },
  };
}

async function getData(slug: string) {
  const res = await fetch(`${HOST}/api/news/${slug}`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  // The return value is *not* serialized
  // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.

  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function Page({ params, searchParams }: Props) {
  const { slug } = params;
  const data = await getData(slug);

  if (data) {
    return <Post data={data[0]} slug={slug} />;
  } else return <Nodata />;
}
```

error.tsx (the Errorboundary component):

```
"use client"; // Error components must be Client Components

import ErrWrapper from "@/wrappers/ErrWrapper";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Error({
  error,
  reset,
}: {
  error: Error;
  reset: () => void;
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Log the error to an error reporting service
    console.error(error);
  }, [error]);

  return <ErrWrapper title="Whoops! Something went wrong..." img="oops.png" />;
}
```

not-found.tsx (404 page):

```
import ErrWrapper from "@/wrappers/ErrWrapper";

export default function NotFound() {
  return <ErrWrapper title="404 - Document not found" img="404.gif" />;
}
```